# Send Data from one Component to another in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two Components. One Component is FileTree and the other is App.

In my FileTree Component I export the whole App. Also I return the data I want to work with in the other Component.

I export the whole App:

```
export const FileTree: FC<FileNode> = ({ name, isDirectory, file }) => { whole code ....

return (

      renderFileTree(fileTree)

);}
```

In the other Component I call the Component  `<FileTree file={selectedFile} ></FileTree></div></div>`. How can I get the result of the Component in TypeScript Code? So I can work with it?

Comment: What does `renderFileTree` return? Also please add the App component code as well.

Comment: What is "the result of the component" and how do you want to "work with it"?  What's actually not working as expected in the code shown?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: the renderFileTree Component returns the code i want to use in typescript. It is a string

Comment: @testuser: If `renderFileTree` returns a string then that means `FileTree` returns a string, which means it's not a JSX component and shouldn't attempt to be rendered as one.  To "get the result" you'd call the function, not try to render it as a component.

Comment: can you give me a example @David

Comment: @testuser: An example of what?  How to call a function and use the result of that function?  That should really be covered by pretty much any introductory JavaScript tutorial.  Technically your `FileTree` "component" does exactly that... It calls the `renderFileTree` function and it returns the result of that function.  The problem is that it's not a component at all (at least based on the information provided here), it's just a wrapper for a function call which adds nothing.  It's not really clear what led you to trying this instead of just calling the function, and a [mcve] might help.

Comment: https://react-ts-7blpuz.stackblitz.io